# JAVA control panel

Tags: java, jnlp

I was doing some research on JWS application and while doing that I clicked on JAVA icon in control panel. I saw java control panel window. I saw the temporary internet files there, It showed me all the JWS application installed on my system. I deleted all of them one by one.
After this I tried to install some demo application again but everytime I click on View icon on JAVA control panel, it become inaccessible and doesn't respond at all.

When i tried to close it using window task manager, It prompt me that It is waiting for a response my side. I dont know which response it is looking for.
I am attaching the screen shot to give more visibility. Can anyone suggest me something what is going wrong here?
[image]

Comment: Try to run command "javaws -viewer". That should open JWS viewer directly.

Answer (score 1):

If it crashes even when running from cmd as:

```
javaws -viewer
```

Then I would recommend, that you [reinstall JRE](http://www.java.com/en/download/).